# Error: The function "getLine" must have a prototype

Tags: c++, unix

I am trying to read string with spaces using getLine, but i am getting  error **"Error: The function "getLine" must have a prototype."**. I am getting this error even after including using namespace std;

```
   void buildAhardCodedSQL4() 
    {
       cout << "Enter source : ";
       getLine(cin,source);
    }
```

Comment: There is no `getLine` in namespace `std`. Perhaps you mean `getline` (all lower case letters).

Comment: after replacing it with getline(cin,source); i am getting new error " Error: Could not find a match for std::getline<std::charT, st                                             d::traits, std::Allocator>(std::istream, char[30]) needed in buildAhardCodedSQL4)."

Comment: 1. Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) 2. Stop using character arrays for strings.

Comment: I am writing this code in unix for oracles. So, I cant use string datatype @n.m.

Comment: "in unix for oracles". Doesn't parse, but anyway. If you cannot use std::string, the language you are writing in is not C++. It could be C++ minus an unknown set of features plus an unknown set of changes. People who know C++ generally have no clue how to write in that language.

Comment: I don.t to how but somehow gets(source) worked for me. and thanks for your help@n.m.

Comment: `gets` is **dangerous** and should **never ever** be used. Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `getLine(cin,source);` with `getline(cin,source);`

For more information on how to use `getline()`, refer to the following: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Answer (score -1):

read the manual:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  // greet the user
  std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  std::getline(std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Hello " << name << ", nice to meet you.\n";

  // read file line by line
  std::istringstream input;
  input.str("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n");
  int sum = 0;
  for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); ) {
    sum += std::stoi(line);
  }
  std::cout << "\nThe sum is: " << sum << "\n";
}
```